# How to enable SSL in MySQL during install time?

Tags: mysql, ssl, installation

My requirement is to enable SSL for the MySQL instance during installation time.

As per the documentation, I understood that, for versions > 5.7.5, the SSL certificates and keys are auto-generated. But looks like we have to update the my.cnf file with those keys and restart the server to enable the SSL encryption for the database connections.

Is there anyway to do this during installation time so that I can avoid manual update of my.cnf and restart of the MySQL server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can always create a shell script that installs MySQL and then modifies `my.cnf` accordingly.

Comment: After modification of `my.cnf` I have to again restart the server which I am trying to avoid.